# Как упаковать проект в один exe-файл?

Tags: c++, opengl

У меня есть проект в Visual Studio, в котором я подключаю библиотеки OpenGL. Столкнулся с необходимостью запаковать его вместе со всеми текстурами и библиотеками в один exeшник. Прочитав статью на Хабре про ILMerge, попробовал им воспользоваться, но при сборке проекта вылетает ошибка.

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов ILMerge не сработает для проекта на С++ (даже для С++/CLI в случае смешанного режима, когда в сборке есть нативный код), поэтому текст ошибки мало что даст. Автору явно нужен другой упаковщик.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, ИМХО, Ваш "месаджь" должен быть отправлен не мне,  а автору вопроса. А если его еще снабдить рекомендациями - то это уже будет не "месаджь", а полноценный ответ. :).

Comment: Необходимо прилинковать сторонние библиотеки статически, а текстуры положить в ресурсы.

Comment: @VTT Можно подробнее пояснить про линковку? А то с плюсами я не очень дружу. Я добавил библиотеку glut32.lib через свойства->компоновщик->ввод->дополнительные зависимости. Текстуры вроде бы лежат в ресурсах https://imgur.com/Z2iHw9m, но скомпилированный exe-файл явно не содержит в себе текстуры, т.к. он слишком маленького размера.